How to use static c# method with return parameter
I have c# dll with class TimSort, that realizes TimSort algorithm. The main method -
public static List<double> Sort(List<double> mainList, bool enterCompare = true)
In Wolfram 14.1 I use:
Needs["NETLink`"];
InstallNET[];
LoadNETAssembly["D:\\work\\Wolfram\\SortTypes.dll"];
LoadNETAssembly["System.Collections"];
Listtype = LoadNETType["System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double]"]
list = NETNew[Listtype];
list@Add[3];
list@Add[2];
list@Add[1];
list1 = TimSort`Sort[list];

But after using TimSort method, list1 becomes
TimSort`Sort[NETObject[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double]]]
and I can't use it like array arr = list1@ToArray[]
What have I do to fix It?
